# Orchestrator is not available with fresh Rook instance

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, helm

I'm trying to set up a rook Ceph cluster on my kubernetes cluster.

Topography:

- 3 kubernetes nodes (all are master/worker pods)
- Each node has /dev/vdX on it for ceph
- Each node is intended to work as part of the ceph cluster

I deployed Rook operator with the helm chart with the following values:

```
image:
  tag: v1.5.8
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 256Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 256Mi
enableFlexDriver: false
enableDiscoveryDaemon: true
```

After that was fully initialized, I tried creating a cluster with the following manifest.

```
apiVersion: ceph.rook.io/v1
kind: CephCluster
metadata:
  name: maincluster
  namespace: rook
spec:
  cephVersion:
    image: ceph/ceph:v15.2.9
  dataDirHostPath: /var/lib/rook
  mon:
    count: 3
    allowMultiplePerNode: false
  mgr:
    modules:
    - name: pg_autoscaler
      enabled: false
  dashboard:
    enabled: true
    ssl: true
  monitoring:
    enabled: false
    rulesNamespace: rook
  cleanupPolicy:
    sanitizeDisks:
      method: quick
  storage: # cluster level storage configuration and selection
    useAllNodes: true
    useAllDevices: true
```

Most things seem to work after running just those.  One pod show errors, but it doesn't seem to be related to the current issue I'm having; seems to rather be a symptom (it's the csi-rbdplugin pod).

I can load the dashboard just fine with an ingress I created.  However, when, on the dashboard, I try to create an OSD or do much of anything, I get a popup saying

> Orchestrator is not available. Please consult the documentation on how to configure and enable the functionality.

The documenation link it has there brings me to [this 404 page](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/docs/octopus/mgr/orchestrator), so that isn't much help.

I've tried searching elsewhere but there doesn't seem to be much info on that specific error message.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong that the Orchestrator is not available and I cannot do much of anything?

Comment: The orchestrator module is part of the MGR service. Does your ceph cluster have at least one MGR up and running? I'm not familiar with rook so I wouldn't know how to make sure MGR is started successfully.

Comment: I have the same problem, what was your solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of this warning and enable orchestrator.

First of all install Rook Toolbox by following this [howto](https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/master/Documentation/ceph-toolbox.md)

Then exec into toolbox: `kubectl -n rook-ceph exec -it rook-ceph-tools-78cdfd976c-sclh9 -- /bin/bash`

And once there, run following commands:

```
[root@rook-ceph-tools-78cdfd976c-sclh9 /]# ceph mgr module enable rook
[root@rook-ceph-tools-78cdfd976c-sclh9 /]# ceph orch set backend rook
[root@rook-ceph-tools-78cdfd976c-sclh9 /]# ceph orch status
Backend: rook
Available: True
```

`ceph orch status` should show the output as in above example.

After that I have no more warnings in Rook Dashboard.

Comment: Nice. May I ask how did you got the dashboard up. I am facing some issue. https://github.com/rook/rook/issues/10532

Comment: @Sanjeev there are couple of yaml files which starts with dashboard in rook ceph deployment directory. you can use either depending on your needs.

Comment: Even though I was using Rook 1.11 and Ceph 17.2.5, I still had to run these commands manually. Maybe this was due to the fact that I didn't have >= 3 OSDs at first?

Answer (score 2):

While the `orchestrator` Ceph module is enabled by default, the `rook` Ceph module is disabled by default.

For anyone using the Rook Helm Charts (as of Rook version 1.12.2, tested with Ceph Reef 18.2.0). You can enable the `rook` module using the following helm chart values:

Ref: https://rook.github.io/docs/rook/v1.12/Storage-Configuration/Monitoring/ceph-dashboard/?h=modules#visualization-of-physical-disks-section-in-the-dashboard

For the Rook Orchestrator [Helm Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/rook/rook-ceph):

```yaml
enableDiscoveryDaemon: true # Not strictly necessary to enable the rook module, but is a pre-requisite to enable features from it.
```

For the Rook Cluster [Helm Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/rook/rook-ceph-cluster):

```yaml
cephClusterSpec:
  mgr:
    modules:
      - name: pg_autoscaler # This is already enabled by default, but needs to be here so that we don't override the default behavior.
        enabled: true
      - name: rook # This enables the rook module.
        enabled: true
```

This can be applied using declarative config, whereas the current answer would need manual intervention to configure.